# Find Repo/Image In Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to pull an image from a Docker registry. I have gone to

http://1.1.1.1/v2/_catalog

And I get a list of all the repos. Then I go to

http://1.1.1.1/v2/repo1/tags/list

And I get a list of all the tags

But what I dont know is when Im trying to pull the image, how do I reference this repo/tag?

I've tried:
docker pull http://1.1.1.1/v2/repo1
docker pull http://1.1.1.1/v2/repo1/tags/latest

I've tried googling it and I just cant find an answer. Im really not sure why. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote with zero information or even a post, whoever you are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
docker pull 1.1.1.1/repo1:latest
```

The command format is:

```
docker pull <host>:<port>/<repoName>:<repoTag>
```

If you are pulling image from docker hub, docker client will add the default IP and port of docker hub for you, so you don't need to specific the IP address. But for a private registry, you need to tell docker client where is your image located.

Comment: I tried docker pull http://1.1.1.1/repo1:latest but I get the error 'not a valid repository or tag'. Am I right to assume that all the listings in /v2/_catalog are repositories? Is there a way to just list repositories?

Comment: @Sugitime Yes, /v2/_catalog will return json list of repositories, please check the registry API doc for details. Can you post your /v2/_catalog output and the command you were use for docker pull, so people can check your steps for you.